# How can I set the maximum height on a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-widget

I would like to create a UI where half of the screen is a ListView and the bottom half is another view. Not sure how to specify the maximum height for the ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Hello StockTwits!"/>


<ListView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/ListView"></ListView><ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"><LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutST" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"><ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutChart" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="View 2"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutDetails" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="View 3"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've created a solution to this at http://chintanrathod.com/maxheightscrollview-in-android-using-android-studio/

Answer (score 0):

You could set the weight of both elements to 1.  This will cause them to take up the same amount of space on the screen, provided niether needs to be larger than half.

Answer (score -1):

set your parent Linearlayout wieght sum is "2"
then set your listview weight 1, and set otherview weight also 1

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2" >


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView><ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutST" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"><ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/icon"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutChart" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="View 2"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutDetails" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="View 3"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>



</LinearLayout>
```

i have changed your code now try this one

Answer (score -7):

solved by setting max height to 200dp

Comment: *How* did you set the maximum height of the ListView to 200dp?! Looks like ListView has a "minHeight" property but no "maxHeight" property...

Comment: he probably did `android:layout_height="200dp"`

Comment: If you solved, test your view on HD(1080pxl) device, u ll never get universal solution for different resolution device such a way